# Converting .xlsx to .pdf with PHPExcel in Kohana

Tags: php, excel, pdf, phpexcel, kohana

I am using Kohana and I have a problem with converting an xlsx file to *.pdf.

This is my code for generating a PDF:

```
        $rendererName=PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
        $rendererLibrary = 'DomPDF.php';
        $rendererLibraryPath = APPPATH."modules/phpexcel/vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/".$rendererLibrary;

        if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
            $rendererName,
            $rendererLibraryPath
        )) {
            die(
                'Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
                PHP_EOL .
                ' as appropriate for your directory structure'
            );
        }
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($spreadsheet);
        $objWriter->save("php://output");
```

And here is the spreadsheet variable: 
`$spreadsheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5')->load('modules/phpexcel/vendor/template.xlsx');`

When I try to run this code I get a response

> PHPExcel_Writer_Exception [ 0 ]: PDF Rendering library has not been defined.

Could anyone help? I suppose the problem could be in my phpdom including code, but I have no idea how to fix it in Kohana.

Comment: You need to set `$rendererLibraryPath` to the folder where you've installed the DomPDF library, not to PHPExcel's wrapper class..... this value tells PHPExcel where to look for DomPDF itself; it already knows where it's own wrapper classes are stored

Comment: So if I put dompdf in /application/vendor/dompdf, then my code would look like this 

`$rendererLibrary = 'autoload.inc.php';
$rendererLibraryPath = APPPATH."vendor/dompdf/".$rendererLibrary;`?

Tried this, but still get the same error though path is correct

Comment: `$rendererLibrary = 'autoload.inc.php';` No! PHPExcel needs to know which library you're using, DomPDF, mPDF, etc..... that's what the `$rendererLibrary` value is telling it.... that's how it knows which wrapper to use